# FileMaker Server 9 and .to6 files: Why doesn't it open them?

Tags: windows, mac-osx, database, filemaker

I have a bunch of .to6-Files that get opened without a problem with FileMaker Server 9 on Mac.

Now I copied them to a Windows box with FMS9, and they are not even detected by the admin console. Is there anything Mac-specific about ".TO6"-Files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was simply to add .to6 under the registered run-time solution file extensions in the FileMaker Server admin console.

Answer (score 0):

Never heard of FileMaker using a .to6 file. Does it work on the Windows side if you simply rename the files to .fp7?